# Struggling with League of Legends Machine Learning with OCI lab - issues applying Terraform

Tags: machine-learning

https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/dbpm/livelabs/run-workshop?p210_wid=3398&p210_wec=&session=13247641550315

Wondering if anyone can help me here - I'm doing the Oracle League of Legends ML lab and have run into an issue while trying to deploy with Terraform and Ansible. Terraform will initialize, but not apply, and it gives the error:

**│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on datascience.tf line 24, in resource "oci_datascience_notebook_session" "lol_notebook_session":
│   24:     shape = data.oci_datascience_notebook_session_shapes.ds_shapes.notebook_session_shapes[0].name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.oci_datascience_notebook_session_shapes.ds_shapes.notebook_session_shapes is empty list of object
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the collection has no elements.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on datascience.tf line 44, in output "ds_notebook_session_shape":
│   44:   value = data.oci_datascience_notebook_session_shapes.ds_shapes.notebook_session_shapes[0].name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.oci_datascience_notebook_session_shapes.ds_shapes.notebook_session_shapes is empty list of object
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the collection has no elements.**

I understand what an empty list is, but since I am following the lab prompts and didn't create the list myself, I'm not sure what to do about it. Has anyone done this lab and come across this?